# Инлайн-кнопки телеграм бот

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Пишу бота для телеграм библиотекой pyTelegramBot, у меня есть шаблонный словарь из ключей которого я хочу сделать инлайн-кнопки в 3 ряда.
Этим кодом получилось получить список только из 1 ряда.

```
def del_function(call):

    data = json.load(open('users.json'))
    inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    
    for k in data:
        inline.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=k, callback_data='users_list'))

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери', reply_markup=inline)
```

Подскажите что не так?

```
data = json.load(open('users.json'))
i = 0
leight = len(data)
while i < leight:
    for k, v in data.items():
        i += 1
        inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3) 
        addl = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=data[k], callback_data='users_list')
        inline.row(addl)
bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери', reply_markup=inline)
```

Выводит так же, в 1 столбец.

Answer (score 0):

**Надеюсь помог :)**

```
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button_update = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кнопка1", callback_data="button1")
        button_bwt = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кнопка2", callback_data="button2")
        keyboard.add(button_update, button_bwt)
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Коментарии на верху кнопок',reply_markup=keyboard)     
        @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
        def answer(call):
# Что будет происходить после нажатие на "Кнопка1"
            if call.data == 'button1': 
            

# Что будет происходить после нажатие на "Кнопка2"
            elif call.data == "button2":
```